# Given two arrays of length n and n - 1, order the first array such that no partial sum is in the second array

Tags: algorithms, integers, constraint-satisfaction

Two arrays of natural numbers are given of length $n$ and $n - 1$:

e.g.

$A: [a_0, a_1,..., a_{n-1}, a_n]$

$B: [b_0, b_1, ..., b_{n-2}, b_{n-1}]$

All elements of $A$ are unique (can be in $B$), all elements of $B$ are unique (can be in $A$) and
every element of $B$ is smaller than the sum of all elements of $A$.

Find a solution $S$ which is a reordering of $A$ (so f.e. for $n=2, S: [a_1,a_0,a_2]$) such that $S_0$ (0th element) is not in $B$, $S_0 + S_1$ is not in $B$, $S_0 + S_1 + S_2$ is not in $B$, etc.

for example:

$A: [1, 2, 3]$

$B: [1, 2]$

Possible solutions:
$S: [3, 2, 1] \lor [3,1,2]$

Furthermore, there is always at least one solution (seems logical as $B$ contains one less element and all it's elements are smaller than the sum of $S$, but don't see how to prove this fact).

The algorithm I have right now is simply going through the permutations and backtracking if the solution doesn't work out. This takes too long but I'm having trouble finding an alternative. Is there some mathematical property I'm missing?

Comment: Can you share the source for this problem (where you encountered it)?

Comment: Are the numbers in $A,B$ likely to be not too large?  Have you tried applying dynamic programming?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, nothing can be assumed about the size or numbers in $A$ or $B$ other than what was stated above. Also I'm not too familiar with dynamic programming but I think having a solution for $n$ doesn't imply it will also work for $n+1$ as the new element in $B$ could be any element in $A$. Furthermore with backtracking I'm only going through every permutation at most once.

Comment: Seems likely that this comes from some programming contest. It's also [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767884/permutation-of-a-sequence-of-integers-where-partial-sum-never-reaches-given-valu) although the answer provided is simply backtracking search.

Comment: Yet I believe it is a fairly interesting question. Actually the existence of at least one solution seems highly likely to be true but non-trivial.

Comment: A big issue with backtracking is that it takes a very long time if the elements of $B$ are near the end of the solution (close to sum $S$), or in the case of backtracking back to front, near the front.